# Android Media Player setVolume method seems to be has no effect

Tags: media-player

I coded the snippet below.

I intended to increase the volume level smoothly.

I inspected the newValue float variable and it really changes its value from 0 to 1 in 0.1 steps nearly.

The intCurrentVolue variable comes from AudioManager, through getStreamVolume method.

```
private void increaseVolume(int intCurrentVolume){
        if (mpLoop !=null){
            float i=0;
            float newValue=0;
            while (i < intCurrentVolume){
            newValue=i/intCurrentVolume;
            try{
                mpLoop.setVolume(newValue,newValue);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            //Here Toast to show Exception
            }
                i++;

                }//while
        }//if

    }//increase
```

Whatever *newValue* value has volume level is always the same.

I have experienced *newValue=0*, but nothing happens.

Thank you.

============================= FIND A SOLUTION =========================

I find out an direction to solve this. [Here](http://myuniverseofandroid.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/functionality-to-fade-soundmusic-gently.html?spref=bl).

I write some code in order to better approach:

1 - Create a Class:

```
package x.x.x.x.x;//your package here

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.media.AudioManager; 
import android.media.MediaPlayer; 


public abstract class Musica extends Activity { 
        static MediaPlayer mp; 
        public static void play(Context context, int resource){ 
        stop(context); 
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(context,resource); 
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        mp.setLooping(true); 
        mp.start(); 
        }//play 

        public static void stop(Context context){ 
        if (mp != null){ 
        mp.stop(); 
        mp.release(); 
        mp = null; 
        }//if 
        }//stop 
}//class
```

2 - Create variables-field of MainActivity:

```
MediaPlayer mp, mpLoop;
AudioManager am;
```

3 - Create a method to better organization:

```
private void prepareFadeOut(){ 
                //----------------
        int targetVol = 0; 
        int STEP_DOWN=1; 
        int currentVol = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        int orgVol=currentVol; 
        // fade music gently 
        while(currentVol > targetVol) { 
        try { 
        Thread.sleep(200); 
        }catch (InterruptedException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, currentVol - STEP_DOWN,0); 
        currentVol =am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        } 
        Musica.stop(MainActivity.this); 
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, orgVol, 0);
}//prepare
```

3 - On a event click of a button (myBt) on my MainActivity:

```
myBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//Context here is MainActivity
//Second parameter is int of my music on raw folder
prepareFadeOut();
Musica.play(MainActivity.this,globalIntMyResourceLoop);
}//onClick
});//setOn
```

Hope this help.